# Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Server - KVM with Spice or VNC

Tags: linux, ubuntu, kvm-virtualization, vnc

I am wondering if anyone has gotten Spice Server or VNC Server to work remotely on ubuntu 20.04? I would be glad to make a video tutorial once I have it working correctly because I can barely find information online (at least that is up to date).
Background:
I have installed a new Ubuntu Server 20.04 LTS on to a Dell PowerEdge 2900, Dual CPU with 48GB ram. I have a "Windows Server 2019" installed inside as a KVM.
Virt-Manager already has Spice Server and VNC Server pre-built into the Virtual Manager. (one this I noticed is every time I change the port it changed back to the default 5900 even if I edit the XML)
I have the router forwarding the port, but that starts by going to the Hypervisor when I need to get to the VM that is on the Hypervisor.
So I have the VM all set up and ready, I just need to get Spice Server or VNC connected or configured properly for production. (Only two VM needs to reach the outside world, al other VMs will only be used on the local network and that works fine)

Comment: What is the problem you are having?

Comment: Trying to figure out the correct configuration and port forwarding, and which display server to go with. It is a clean install, I'm trying to figure out how to set up to remote into the KVM machine from outside of the network. I have the Spice viewer on a Windows 10 computer that is going through a VPN. Im just trying to get the IP and custom port of the Hypervisor to route to the KVM machine. (Custom port to separate which computer the client is connecting too.) (I can remote into the hypervisor fine, now trying to get into the KVM machine)

Comment: Most of us just use an ssh tunnel. Any reason why you don't want to do this?

Comment: For all the local VMs i can just SSH in or use the Virt viewer from the hypervisor, but one of the VMs is specifically a Windows 10 VM to run accounting software that needs to be GUI accessed remotely by my business partners on the other side of the USA.